# FullCalendar DayGrid multi-day event splitting

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

We're using a **FullCalendar v5** React component for event display - the data is fetched from an API.

On DayGrid's Month View, I'd like to split the events into multiple columns for different categories, as seen here:

[Event types split into columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxAPX.png)

Done using custom CSS. The issue is that multiple-day events stretch across the days they occurred on, and so the percentage styling (for example, 'take up 33% of the box width') goes the full width ('take up 33% of 3 boxes width'). It's hard to even tell what day it occurs on.

Is there a way to split the events into multiple days, like in TimeGrid's week and day view?

[Like in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWDzH.png)

Thanks!

Comment: No, you've have to create a completely custom view for that. P.S. what you're doing sounds like it would be ideal for the Scheduler add-on which splits things into "resources" (analagous to your categories potentially, I would suggest, or at least usable to represent them). Unfortunately the month view still doesn't support resources, but most of the other views do.

Comment: Gotcha. That might be the answer I was looking for -- maybe I'll just mess with the API to split the events there. Thanks!